# Ruby each iterator returning array rather than boolean

Tags: ruby, each, enumerable

I have code like the following (truncated/paraphrased for readability)

```
def board_check?
  @board.each {|row| check_row_for_truth_conditions(row)}
end

def check_row_for_truth_conditions(row)
  return true if row.include("foo")
  false
end
```

Right now the implicit return of that each iterator is always the collection it is iterating over. ie; I get the array back, not true or false. If I don't refactor and do something like the following, it works as expected. However I use the check_row_for_truth_conditions in many places (and it is much longer), so would like to refactor it out

```
def board_check?
  @board.each do |row| 
    return true if row.include("foo")
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: I figured it out. I can get what I want by using any? instead of each. So `@board.any? {|row| check_row_for_truth_conditions(row)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of the block passed to each (`false`) is thrown away. The explicit return works because that returns from the method, not the block. You instead want:

```
def board_check?
  @board.each do |row| 
    return true if row.include("foo")
  end
  return false
end
```

But really you want to use [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
def board_check?
  @board.any? do |row| 
    row.include("foo")  # or perhaps check_row_for_truth_conditions(row)
  end
end
```

Also, your check_row_for_truth_conditions can be simplified to just this:

```
def check_row_for_truth_conditions(row)
  row.include("foo")
end
```

No need for the explicit return `true`/`false`.

Comment: Thanks! figured out I should use any right as you were typing :) I'll accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 3):

One option is:

```
def board_check?
  @board.any? {|row| row.include("foo") }
end
```